# How to make redirect from from specific category to another website

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, url, redirect, directory

Please advice how to make the following redirect:

> www.siteA.com/**directory**/keep-all-those-urls/ → www.siteB.com/**directory**/keep-all-those-urls/

But at same time do **not** redirect other directories:

> www.siteA.com/ → www.siteA.com/ *(no redirect here)*

Comment: So when user enter into `www.siteA.com/directory/keep.../` you need to create an index.html which will contain a .js file with redirection, or the best is to create a server file (.php, .aspx.cs, ...) with the redirection (better server side).

Comment: Could you give an example of such .js or php redirects please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `/directory/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?siteA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ www.siteB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function reDirection(){
  var currentDomain= location.host; // might be wwww.siteA.com
  var currentPath = location.pathname;
  var reDirectionUrl = "www.site2.com"; // www.site2.com
  var reDirectionUrl = (currentPath != "/")? reDirectionUrl+currentPath : currentDomain;
  window.location = "http://"+reDirectionUrl;
```

}